# I have started taking the course in java Programming methodology(CS106A) available at stanford website

Tags: java

I am trying to do Karel the robot assignment 1 (midPointFindingKarel) and since I am new to Java I don't understand why my code does not read the method `movingWest` at all. As far as my logic goes it should.(After finishing the method 'movingEast' program stops). Since I am a beginner I am sure I am missing something important. Could somebody help me out with an answer so I can understand the logic.

```
import stanford.karel.*;

public class MidpointFindingKarel1 extends SuperKarel {
    public void run() {
        puttingBeepers();
        while(beepersPresent()) {
            movingEast();
            movingWest();
        }
    }

    private void puttingBeepers() {
        while(frontIsClear()) {
            if (noBeepersPresent()) {
                putBeeper();
            }
            move();
        }
        putBeeper();
    }

    private void movingEast() {
        cornerBeepersPickUp();
        while(beepersPresent()) {
            if(frontIsClear()) {
                move();
            }
        }
    }

    private void movingWest() {
        cornerBeepersPickUp();
    }

    private void cornerBeepersPickUp() {
        turnAround();
        pickBeeper();
        move();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess that you are stuck in the while loop in `movingEast`, which would mean `beepersPresent` is always returning true. Can you verify either way?

Comment: That is exactly what's happening 'beepersPresent' is always true so it does not go to the next line.  It is in an infinite loop. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: I'm going to make an answer then, if you wouldn't mind accepting it, if you think it is helpful. (You'll even get a small rep bonus). Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by the other answers it is because your loop does not exit from the movingeast. As a solution you would make what is referred to as a "nested" statement, where you include the if-else statement:

```js
> while(beeperspresent()) {
if (frontIsClear) {
movingeast;
} else {
movingwest;
}
```

(Note: The frontisClear condition is just one of many possible options. you can change it to whatever fits your assignment as long as it is a legal condition.)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say considering there is no reference block for some of the methods in the above code.  Going on a hunch here you might want to check out the difference between while and Do-While loops in Java as it may have something to do with the beepersPresent() conditional in movingEast() breaking the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is that you aren't exiting the while loop in `movingEast`. This would mean that `beepersPresent` is always returning true.